# Ros packages for RGBD SLAM with Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, 3dslam, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I wanted to perform RGBD SLAM with kinect what are the packages that are available for ROS-INDIGO?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223093/ros-packages-for-rgbd-slam-with-kinect/) by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RGBDSLAM V2 is available and works well. There is a decent amount of explanation and instructions here:
http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/

The documentation lists it as using [openni_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch), but it works with [freenect_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/freenect_launch) as well.

One note about installing RGBDSLAM V2 is that you may experience an error during compiling due to SiftGPU, such as `*** [build/CuTexImage.o] Error 1`. If this happens, you can adjust the CMakeLists.txt file to turn off SiftGPU by changing the line `set(USE_SIFT_GPU        1)` to `set(USE_SIFT_GPU        0)`.

Hopefully this can get you started.

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2015-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on 2015-12-26**:
But it says it is for ros groovy . will it also work for indigo?

**Comment by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) on 2015-12-26**:
Sorry, I didn't explicitly state that it works for Indigo. Some of the documentation is outdated, but if you look on the GitHub link there will be a branch for Indigo, which is fully functional.

**Comment by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on 2015-12-27**:
thank you for your help. i git cloned the package to my workspace , but while executing "rosdep install rgbdslam_v2"
i get following error:
ERROR: ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource rgbdslam_v2
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros

**Comment by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) on 2015-12-27**:
Two things to mention here,

1. The package name is `rgbdslam`, not `rgbdslam_v2`. If you look in the launch files thats how it is referred to. So try running `rosdep install rgbdslam`.
2. Based on the error output from Rosdep, it doesn't look like you have a catkin workspace setup. Did you clon

**Comment by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on 2015-12-28**:
yes thank you, you were right the problem was with my catkin workspace :)